# Using roxygen2 for R functions in an R package containing R/Cpp code

Tags: c++, r, rcpp, r-package

I have a Cpp function that is called inside an R function using Rcpp packgae. The R function accepts an `inputDataFrame` and uses the Cpp function (also accepts a DataFrame) to calculate drug amounts `(A1)` as a function of time. R then returns the `inputDataFrame` with added column for the calculated amounts `A1`.

I want to documnet the R functions (rather than the Cpp functions) using `roxygen2` package in RStudio. However, when I used `roxygen2` comments (as below), it did not generate the *.RD files and help pages the way you expected to do upon building the model. Please note that I have no trouble using roxygen2 when my package contains only R functions. In the latter case `*.RD` files and help pages are generated automatically as expected.

Any hints on how to do that?

Comment: Your `@description` etc. annotations are already roxygen comments. Use `devtools::document()` to create a documentation from that. See http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/man.html#man-workflow for more details.

Comment: Yep. Thank you. But when I run an example using the packge `pharm`, I end up with this error: ` Error in .Call("pharm_OneCompIVbolusCpp", PACKAGE = "pharm", inputFrame) : 
  "pharm_OneCompIVbolusCpp" not available for .Call() for package "pharm" `

Comment: Is there a way to make the Cpp function available to the R-function?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C++ function not available](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36605955/c-function-not-available)

Answer (score 6):

Of course you can do that.

**First** create a package, either via the helper feature in RStudio or by calling `Rcpp.package.skeleton()`.

**Second** create a roxygen block in your C++ source file. See a million examples on GitHub as eg [this recent example one of mine](https://github.com/eddelbuettel/rcppcctz/blob/master/src/utilities.cpp#L8-L28).

**Third** tell Rcpp to create the C++ -> R bindings: call `compileAttributes()`.  RStudio would do this for you.  *Now you have roxygen markup in R* (as eg [seen here](https://github.com/eddelbuettel/rcppcctz/blob/master/R/RcppExports.R#L32-L51)).

**Fourth** have Roxygen process the markup. You can enable this in RStudio, I just call (a helper script calling) `roxygen2::roxygenize(".", roclets="rd")`. This create [the manual page](https://github.com/eddelbuettel/rcppcctz/blob/master/man/tzDiff.Rd)

And now you have a package with an R function calling a C++ function.

And all that has been explained for years in [the corresponding Rcpp Attributes vignette](https://cloud.r-project.org/web/packages/Rcpp/vignettes/Rcpp-attributes.pdf).